# Beats1 on Mac doesn’t start unless I logout

Tags: itunes, macos, itunes-radio

Every time I try to listen to Beats1 in iTunes on Mac, I have to log out and log back in, otherwise it doesn’t start. It has absolutely no problem starting if I’m freshly logged in, but if I quit iTunes and then I try to listen again, it doesn’t start unless I do the log out/log in dance. How can I overcome this situation?

I should mention that I’m not an Apple Music subscriber, nor do I want to become one.

I’m on the latest version of Mavericks, if that matters.

Comment: Sounds like a software bug. I'd recommend updating to Yosemite or waiting until El Capitan comes out in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this situation. Even if you use the correct Apple ID to authorize music playback, you may still see a repeat request for authorization. This can happen if you're logged in to your Mac using a simple user account, which doesn't have the correct privileges to allow iTunes to update its internal files with the authorization information.
    The solution is to log out and then log back in using an administrator account. Once you're logged in with an administrator account, launch iTunes, select "Authorize This Computer" from the Store menu, and provide the appropriate Apple ID and password.
    Log out, then log back in with your basic user account. iTunes should now be able to play the song.

Comment: It did not work. Also, it usually _does_ play Beats1 radio, but **only** if I log out and log back in into iTunes.